# Speech Recognition stops listening immediately

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I want to listen the first word from the user. When speech recognition starts I hear the bip-sound, but immediately I hear the stop sound. I observed that onRMSchanged is the only method where something is happening.

This is how I use the SpeechRecognizer. I am connected to the internet when I run the application.

```
        Intent speechintent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        speechintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS , 1000);
        speechintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,  RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        speechintent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en");

        SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(Inference.getmContext());
        speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
            Log.i("beg", "beg");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
                Log.i("on rms changed", "rms changed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
                Log.i("ANSWER","END");
            }

            @Override
            public void onEndOfSpeech() {
                Log.i("ANSWER","END");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int error) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResults(Bundle results) {

               Log.i("ANSWER",results.getString(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS));
                ArrayList<String> result = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
                Log.i("ANSWER",partialResults.getString(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS));
            }

            @Override
            public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

            }
        });

        speechRecognizer.startListening(speechintent);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                speechRecognizer.stopListening();
            }
        }, 1000);
```

I do not know why it doesn't let me speak.

UPDATE:

This is the order it goes through the methods:

```
onRmsChanged
onReadyForSpeech
onError
```

onError I get the error code 2, that means Network Error, but I already set the Google Text To speech, I put `INTERNET` and `RECORD_AUDIO` permissions in Manifest and I am connected to the internet. I do not understand what is wrong?

Comment: Your `postDelayed` is taking a delay of `1000` - 1000 milliseconds is just 1 second. Is that how long you want to be listening for?

Comment: Where are you calling `run` from

Comment: From a non activity class I call run

Comment: @ianhanniballake I wang just to listen to yes/no words and I think 1 sec is enough

Comment: from all overriden methods it goes just in onRMSChanged